# Reset a Stage Variable from another Stage Variable

Tags: datastage

I have a requirement to concatenate multiple lines of data into a single line. The only indentation that multiple lines belong together on a single line is "^" at the end of the last line.  I have tried your recommendation and the stage variable to reset the first(svSetConcatenateLineNull)  will not compile. Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
svSetToNull
SetNull()

svIsRowComplete
right(DsLink.Input_blob, 1) = "^"

svConcatenateLine
svConcatenateLine : DsLink.Input_blob

svSetConcatenateLineNull  **Fails at Compile Time**
if (svIsRowComplete) then svConcatenateLine = svSetToNull
else ""
```

Comment: Yes - set the stagevar2 to null with SetNull() and set the first stageVar to stagevar2. It would be easier to answer if you descibe your use case.

Comment: I agree with MichaelTiefenbacher regarding the question: Please describe your case. The more detailed the question is, the more detailed can be the answer. Stage Variables in a Transformer are processed top-down for each row per partition.

Comment: Hello and Thank you for your input.  I have updated the question to include more information.  Thanks.

Comment: @tbtcust I feel like I just answered this question by answering your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415774/concatenate-multiple-lines-of-data-into-a-single-line

Comment: @tbtcust Regarding your code: You cannot set svConcatenateLine to any value in the then-part of your if statement. You must provide a value to the stage variable. This is trying to produce a boolean, but since you cannot compare to NULL like this, it's failing.

Comment: Hello.  that's true and  it works, except the making svConcatenateLine NULL after the EOL is found.   Is "svConcatenateLine = svSetToNull"  valid?  This causes a compilation error.

Comment: Let's discuss this at your original question

Comment: Thanks.  The ordinal message was I have one Stage Variable that has content.  As part of processing in a second stage variable I'd to reset the content in the first Stage Variable to NULL.   Is this possible?

Comment: @tbtcust, if my answer on the other question worked for you, I would appreciate if you tagged it as solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reset the variable. Just think about processing the variables in top down order for each incoming row.

You can add a conditional value in the last variable and assign that variable to the first variable for the next row.

Initialize your variables in the Stage Variable declaration so they have an appropriate value for the first row per partition.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply.  I was able to process the variables in top down order for each incoming row.  Thank you so much Justus.